# dig behavior on RHEL6

Tags: redhat, dig

dig on RHEL6 has a different behavior than in RHEL5, related to the @server syntax:

```
root@rhel6# dig @some.dnsserver.com any some.example.com
dig: couldn't get address for 'some.dnsserver.com': not found
```

It seems it doesn't try to revolve the parameter for the specified dns server. Any idea why is that?  Is it to avoid making another dns request?

Answer (score 4):

This is normal behavior: If `dig` can't find the address of the nameserver you specified (using the nameservers listed in `/etc/resolv.conf`) it will tell you it "couldn't get address for" your requested server.

Either you typo'd the DNS server name or your local DNS can't map the name to an IP -- Try specifying the nameserver by IP address instead?

Comment: You can test what `dig` would get when it tries to do the lookup of `some.dnsserver.com` by using the command `getent hosts some.dnsserver.com`. See the manual page for getent(1). You may want to use `getent ahosts ...` instead.